# Downloading and parsing list of Getcachine CWGs

Tags: javascript, optimization, ajax

I'm building a page that downloads a list of Geocaching CWGs for my country in XML, and then parse it. The structure of the XML looks like this:

```
<cwgkatalog>
    <cwg>
        <cislo>8245</cislo>
        <id_katalog>8245</id_katalog>
        <kategorie>cwg</kategorie>
        <verze>1</verze>
        <guid>891a8e4d-9dee-4f77-a9c7-8017c5f16b15</guid>
        <jmeno>GarfieldMnHr</jmeno>
        <jpg_oficialni>cwg08245-1.jpg</jpg_oficialni>
        <img>http://cwg.geog.cz/cwg08245-1.jpg</img>
        <odkaz/>
        <komentar/>
        <zarazeno>2013-12-06 00:00:00</zarazeno>
    </cwg>
    <cwg>
...
```

I have a function that searches for `jmeno` property and because of that, I have created an array working as an index array for `jmeno`:

```
function createAjax() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }
}

function CwgParser(xmlListURL) {
    var httpRequest = createAjax(),
        mainContext = this,
        tree_cwgData = [],
        arr_nameIndex = [];


    this.findDataByName = function(searchedName) {
        var lastIndex = arr_nameIndex.indexOf(searchedName),
            arr_foundIndexes = [lastIndex],
            arr_resultData = [];
        while (lastIndex != -1) {
            lastIndex = arr_nameIndex.indexOf(searchedName, lastIndex + 1);
            arr_foundIndexes.push(lastIndex);
        }
        arr_foundIndexes.splice(-1, 1);

        arr_foundIndexes.forEach(function(value) {
            arr_resultData.push(tree_cwgData[value]);
        });
        return (arr_resultData.length == 0) ? false : arr_resultData;
    };

    this.parseXML = function(xmlData) {
        var _xmlDoc, _parser, _arr_parts, _node_currentNode, _obj_currentNodeData, arr_cwgList = [], nameIndex = [];
        if (window.DOMParser) {
            _parser = new DOMParser();
            _xmlDoc = _parser.parseFromString(xmlData, 'text/xml');
        } else {
            _xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
            _xmlDoc.async = false;
            _xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlData);
        }

        _arr_parts = _xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('cwg');

        for (var i = 0; i < _arr_parts.length; i++) {
            _node_currentNode = _arr_parts[i];
            _obj_currentNodeData = {};
            for (var j = 1; j < _arr_parts[i].childNodes.length - 1; j=j+2) {
                _obj_currentNodeData[_node_currentNode.childNodes[j].nodeName] = _node_currentNode.childNodes[j].innerHTML;
            }
            nameIndex.push(_obj_currentNodeData.jmeno.trim());
            arr_cwgList.push(_obj_currentNodeData);
        }

        tree_cwgData = arr_cwgList;
        arr_nameIndex = nameIndex;

        mainContext.ondataparse();
    };

    this.loadXML = function () {
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
                mainContext.ondataload();
                mainContext.parseXML(httpRequest.responseText);
            }
        };
        mainContext.onrequeststart();
        httpRequest.open('GET', './fileContentProvider.php?url=' + xmlListURL, true);
        httpRequest.send(null);
    };

    this.onrequeststart = function() {};
    this.ondataload = function() {};
    this.ondataparse = function() {};
}
```

and I call it like this (`LoadingIcon` is just a support class that creates overlay, displaying loading .gif and some text):

```
var xml = new CwgParser('cwg.geog.cz/cwg.xml'),
    loader = new LoadingIcon('./ajax-loader.gif');
xml.ondataparse = function() {
    loader.stop();
    document.getElementById('container').style.display = 'block';
};
xml.ondataload = function() {
    loader.setText('Parsing CWG list...');
};
loader.setText('Loading CWG list...');
loader.start();
xml.loadXML();
```

Is there any better way of searching and downloading the data?